# Microsoft XP Windows - Mapping application to match access data - "Mappoint"

Tags: excel, ms-access, mapping, mappoint

Does anyone know where I can find a good mapping tool to use in connection with Access data? Similiar to Mappoint but not even as detailed/in-depth. Anything that would work with Access or Excel would be really what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There really aren't a whole lot of options, but you might try looking at this link:
http://theclosetentrepreneur.com/export-excel-data-to-google-maps

---

Edit:
Not a lot of mapPoint alternatives out there that aren't web based. I did find one that says it works with any database. First license is free. $29/license after that.
http://www.cartoworld.com/CartoMAP.html

Comment: i did. but i need something that does not reach out online to function. maybe even a much simpler map function that i can work with in xls??

 i did enjoy reading about it though; thanks for the thought!

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, there isn't really much. The problem is that if an add-in or product exists, it is typically so basic that there isn't a market for it. People will prefer something like Streets & Trips or Delorme for basic map routing, and MapPoint for an API and presentation.

The alternative is to roll your own. You say you don't need much detail so public domain data would be acceptable (and may even need to be cut down to size). A number of open source libraries such as GDAL/OGR can then be used to get the projections and data loading to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was a Streets and Trips user until it was discontinued. Since then I've been using Badger Maps and really love it. They say they can integrate with any CRM so I'm assuming they can work with AccessData too.